# Не переносится элемент

Tags: javascript, html

Подскажите пожалуйста, есть страница на которой можно перенести `<p>` но нельзя перемещать `<button>`.
Подскажите пожалуйста, почему.
Спасибо.

```js
$(function() {

  $('.dragElement').draggable({
    containment: "parent"
  }).filter('#dragH').draggable("option", "axis", "x");

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI</title>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.10.3/themes/sunny/jquery-ui.css">
  <style type="text/css">
    #container {
      border: medium double black;
      width: 700px;
      height: 450px
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="container">
    <p class="dragElement" style="width:100px;height:100px;background: #80de62; border: 1px solid black; font-size:15px; color:white;">
      Перетащить внутри родителя
    </p>
    <p class="dragElement" style="width:100px;height:100px;background: #80de62; border: 1px solid black; font-size:15px; color:white;">
      Перетащить внутри родителя2
    </p>
    <button class="dragElement" style="width:100px;height:100px;background: #80de62; border: 1px solid black; font-size:15px; color:white;">Кнопка</button>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-cancel

```js
$(function() {

  $('.dragElement').draggable({
    containment: "parent",
    cancel: "" // !!! remove default exclusion of input,textarea,button,select,option
  });

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI</title>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.10.3/themes/sunny/jquery-ui.css">
  <style type="text/css">
    #container {
      border: medium double black;
      width: 700px;
      height: 450px
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="container">
    <p class="dragElement" style="width:100px;height:100px;background: #80de62; border: 1px solid black; font-size:15px; color:white;">
      Перетащить внутри родителя
    </p>
    <p class="dragElement" style="width:100px;height:100px;background: #80de62; border: 1px solid black; font-size:15px; color:white;">
      Перетащить внутри родителя2
    </p>
    <button class="dragElement" style="width:100px;height:100px;background: #80de62; border: 1px solid black; font-size:15px; color:white;">Кнопка</button>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Отлично, спасибо большое. Подскажите пожалуйста еще вопрос. Сейчас проверка идет по class="dragElement" то есть если элемент имеет такой класс он будет перетаскиваться, а как сделать проверку по id="dragElement".

Comment: @ВладиславСамохин Пожалуйста. Не забудьте принять ответ - "галочка" слева от ответа. По `id` - `$('#dragElement').draggable({...`. Имейте в виду, что выборка по `id` содержит не больше одного элемента.